# Reverse accumulation to get month by month data in Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have received data with accumulated numbers. Is there a smart way to reverse the accumulation of the data, so I have it month by month and not stacked on top of each other?

Example input:

```
 Date    SalesRep    itemA   
 01-12-2017  X        1      
 01-12-2017  Y        0     
 01-12-2017  Z        0   
 01-01-2018  X        1     
 01-01-2018  Y        1     
 01-01-2018  Z        0    
 01-02-2018  X        1    
 01-02-2018  Y        1    
 01-02-2018  Z        1
```

Desired output:

```
 Date    SalesRep    itemA   
 01-12-2017  X       1      
 01-12-2017  Y       0     
 01-12-2017  Z       0   
 01-01-2018  X       0     
 01-01-2018  Y       1     
 01-01-2018  Z       0    
 01-02-2018  X       0   
 01-02-2018  Y       0    
 01-02-2018  Z       1
```

I am using that script which i reused from the forum.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('File.xlsx')

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)

df = df.sort_values('Date', ascending=False) # This now sorts in date order

cum_columns = ['itemA']

result = df.merge(
df.groupby('SalesRep')[cum_columns].diff(),
left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes=['', '_uncum']
).fillna({'{}_uncum'.format(cum_column): df[cum_column] for cum_column in cum_columns})

print(result)
```

Because for the last month each of the value is 1 then the rest of the months is 0. How can I change the script to work with my case ?

**EDIT**

Using JohnE answer i am getting error please take a look:

```
    Date              SalesRep  ItemA   itemA_diff
    2018-08-01 00:00:00 John    1        1
    2018-07-01 00:00:00 John    1        0
    2018-06-01 00:00:00 John    0        -1
    2018-05-01 00:00:00 John    0        0
    2018-04-01 00:00:00 John    0        0
    2018-03-01 00:00:00 John    0        0
    2018-02-01 00:00:00 John    0        0
    2018-01-01 00:00:00 John    0        0
    2017-12-01 00:00:00 John    0        0
    2017-11-01 00:00:00 John    0        0
    2017-10-01 00:00:00 John    0        0
```

I Should get

```
    Date              SalesRep  ItemA   itemA_diff
    2018-08-01 00:00:00 John    1        0
    2018-07-01 00:00:00 John    1        1
    2018-06-01 00:00:00 John    0        0
    2018-05-01 00:00:00 John    0        0
    2018-04-01 00:00:00 John    0        0
    2018-03-01 00:00:00 John    0        0
    2018-02-01 00:00:00 John    0        0
    2018-01-01 00:00:00 John    0        0
    2017-12-01 00:00:00 John    0        0
    2017-11-01 00:00:00 John    0        0
    2017-10-01 00:00:00 John    0        0
```

What should be changed?

Comment: You just need to sort in forward, not reverse, chronological order:  `df.sort_values('Date')`

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly standard use case for combining `groupby` and `diff` although the syntax can be rather finnicky (see notes below):

```
df = df.sort_values('Date')
df['itemA_diff'] = df.groupby('SalesRep')['itemA'].diff()
df['itemA_diff'] = df['itemA_diff'].fillna(df['itemA'])
```

Results:

```
        Date SalesRep  itemA  itemA_diff
0 2017-01-12        X      1         1.0
1 2017-01-12        Y      0         0.0
2 2017-01-12        Z      0         0.0
3 2018-01-01        X      1         0.0
4 2018-01-01        Y      1         1.0
5 2018-01-01        Z      0         0.0
6 2018-01-02        X      1         0.0
7 2018-01-02        Y      1         0.0
8 2018-01-02        Z      1         1.0
```

Notes:

1. It's important to first sort by "Date" and also that you have converted to a proper pandas datetime with `pd.to_datetime` as needed.
2. I'm not sure why but both "Date" and "itemA" need to be columns and not indexes. (I got weird errors on my initial attempt with "Date" in the index)

**Alternate approach**:  Here's the original answer included at @jezrael's request as it might be faster:

```
df = df.sort_values(['SalesRep','Date'])
df['itemA_diff'] = df['itemA'].diff()
df['itemA_diff'] = np.where( df.SalesRep == df.shift().SalesRep, 
                             df.itemA_diff, 
                             df.itemA )
```

Comment: Without groupby is not faster?

Comment: In my opinion the best is add your old solution bellow new one ;)

Comment: @jezrael  OK, added back in!

Comment: THank you guys but i still have a problem. It is not solving my issue completely. I am getting the wrong answer.

Comment: @Mikul  you have sorted in reverse order, needs to be in standard chronological order: `df.sort_values('Date')`.  You can reverse order after creating the new variable, if you like.